# Auotomate VS Code Run Tasks through command line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio as my IDE. I have multiple run tasks defined in `launch.json` which I can run it from `Run/Debug` menu.

I want to run few specific tasks in some order from `launch.json` very frequently,

So If there is any way to achieve this via command line or aggregrate those tasks into a new launch file and run it.

Any thoughts how can I achieve this?

Comment: what do you use VS or VSC, VS does not have `launch.json`

Comment: you can create a compound launch config

Comment: @rioV8 I use Visual Studio Code. How can i create compound launch config If you can share please an example or link?

Comment: have you read the doc page about debugging?